# Not able to get all records of column

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I want to get employee names (from an SQL database) which fall in a particular date range and display it through response.write.

Why is this loop is not working?

```
 Dim constr6 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cmdpns").ConnectionString
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(constr6)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd8 As New SqlCommand("Select * from insu_dtl WHERE ins_valid Between @c_date And @c_date2 ")
                    cmd8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_date", c_date2)
                    cmd8.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_date2", Session("c_date3"))
                    cmd8.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd8.Connection = conn



                    objreader = cmd8.ExecuteReader()
                    Do Until objreader.Read <> False

                        Session("emp_name") = objreader("emp_name").ToString()
                        Response.Write(Session("emp_name"))
                        Response.Write("working")

                    Loop
```

Comment: When you just want `emp_name` why are you using `*` in `select`. `Select emp_name from insu_dtl WHERE ins_valid Between @c_date And @c_date2`

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2. It has a sample of a loop with a SqlDataReader.

Comment: you r right, issue is not with * in select ... issue is that how to use loop to get all record till end of record

Comment: @ManojBaswal - I dont know `C#`  I was saying that you are unwantedly selecting more columns when you just need one

Answer (score 1):

This bit is (one reason at least) why your loop doesn't work:

```
Do Until objreader.Read <> False
```

objReader.Read returns True when there's a row, so your loop immediately ends. I suspect what you meant was just:

```
Do Until objreader.Read = False
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted - I sensed something was wrong there and simply wrote `While rdr.Read` so that it would work in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one thing going wrong:

- using `BETWEEN` can be tricky
- `AddWithValue` may be confused as to the data type
- using `Response.Write` might be inserting the text somewhere you can't see it

An easy way to get round the `BETWEEN` is to use `x >= A AND x < B` where `A` is the start date and `B` is the (end date + 1 day). Remove any time component from them so that you know exactly what is being supplied to the query.

Instead of `AddWithValue`, explicitly add a parameter with the correct type.

Rather than using `Response.Write`, place an [asp:Literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal(v=vs.110).aspx) control on the page and set its `.Text`.

```
Option Strict On
' ...

' remove any time component from the dates...
Dim startDate As DateTime = c_date2.Date
Dim endDate As DateTime = DirectCast(Session("c_date3"), DateTime).Date.AddDays(1)

Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim constr6 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cmdpns").ConnectionString

Using conn As New SqlConnection(constr6)
    Using cmd8 As New SqlCommand("SELECT [emp_name] FROM [insu_dtl] WHERE [ins_valid] >= @startDate AND [ins_valid] < @endDate", conn)
        cmd8.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@startDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = startDate})
        cmd8.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@endDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = endDate})
        conn.Open()

        Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd8.ExecuteReader()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read
                sb.Append(rdr.GetString(0))

            End While
        End If    

    End Using
End Using

' use an <asp:Literal> control instead of using Response.Write: '
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Also, you can add the connection when you instantiate an SqlCommand, and the default `.CommandType` is `CommandType.Text`, so you don't need to set that.

Comment: If objreader.HasRows Then
                        Do While objreader.Read()

                            Session("emp_name") = objreader("emp_name").ToString()
                            'Response.Write(Session("emp_name"))
                            'Response.Write("working")
                            callname()
                        Loop
                    Else
                        Response.Write(" no row")
                    End If